Radial reparametrization ansatz in Schwarzschild metric derivation
The standard derivation of Schwarzschild solution (and Birkhoff's theorem) seem to begin with the most general spherically symmetric static metric
$$ds^2 = -U(\rho) dt^2 + V(\rho) d\rho^2 + W(\rho) \rho^2 ( d\phi^2 + \sin^2(\phi) d\theta^2)  . $$
Then they proceed to postulate that a radial reparametrization $r^2 = \rho W(\rho)$ is always possible, and dispose of the $W(\rho)$ factor:
$$ ds^2 = -A(r) dt^2 + B(r) dr^2 + r^2 ( d\phi^2 + \sin^2( \phi ) d\theta^2). $$
This seems like a very strong imposition on the solution, as it seems to impose that the $W(\rho)$ has to be monotonic (no shrink or expansion of the throat allowed). In fact the Morris-Thorne wormhole solution seems to never want to impose such restriction on the metric, otherwise there would be no throat.
In fact, I could find more palatable an argument that there can always be a radial reparametrization for which $V(\rho)$ (not $W(\rho)$) can be set to one. That seems a more reasonable simplification.
Is there a proper derivation of the Schwarzschild metric somewhere without this seemingly arbitrary ansatz? I couldn't find any

well, what is r anyaways? a bunch of rulers?

I think the best way to see it is by defining the radius in a geometric way: because of the spherical symmetry, you can define r in terms of the area of the 2-sphere. So, r would be the radius at which $A = 4 \pi r^2$ takes a particular value. This would correspond to your second metric. Note that the area is a coordinate/diffeomorphism-invariant concept.

@Guliano that would be baking the conclusion that area grows monotonically with some parameter into your assumption. What if area could've taken a given value at two or more values of r? those solutions are ruled out by the assumption

Einstein's equations are local. We don't care whether $W(\rho)$ is a monotonic function everywhere. As long as there is some local region where $W(\rho)$ is monotonic, we can define the coordinate $r$ in that local region and solve Einstein's equations there (which then gives the Schwarzschild metric).

@UnkemptPanda that would mean the area of the 2-sphere is growing in one area and shrinking in another one. I think this would require some nonzero stress-energy tensor, like e.g. a nonzero cosmological constant in a certain patch. This would break the assumption that we are looking at a vacuum solution.

@Guliano that is a conclusion you reach after you make the calculation, not while you are formulating it. Write the metric, compute $G_{\mu \nu}$, and see what that says about $T_{\mu \nu}$ (or what junction conditions must the vacuum solution meet). This is supposed to be the first and simplest solution of EFE, and if you need to make all these assumptions beforehand, then there is something clearly wrong here. In any case, if you feel this is an answer, then better write it as an answer, comments are not stable over time.

@Guliano AFAIK, leaving the $W(\rho)$ does not force the $G_{\mu \nu}$ components to be non-zero, but if it does, it is a nontrivial assertion and should be made explicit (so that people can go and look out for the proof). This assertion is also amiss in all the derivations I've seen. if you have a proof of that, I would accept it as an answer.

If we start from the Ansatz
$$ds^2 = -e^{\alpha(\rho)} dt^2 + e^{\beta(\rho)} d\rho^2 + e^{\gamma(\rho)} ( d\phi^2 + \sin^2(\phi) d\theta^2) , $$
(This is equivalent with the OP's original Ansatz as long as $U$, $V$, and $W$ are nonzero. If they were the metric would be degenerate. So this is a safe assumption.)
then the vacuum Einstein equations $R_{tt}=0$ and $R_{\rho\rho}=0$ yield
$$ \alpha''(\rho) = -1/2 \alpha'(\rho) \left[\alpha'(\rho)-\beta'(\rho)+2\gamma'(\rho)\right]$$
$$ \gamma''(\rho) = -1/2 \gamma'(\rho) \left[\alpha'(\rho)+\beta'(\rho)-\gamma'(\rho)\right]$$
The second equation implies that if $\gamma'(\rho)=0$ for any value of $\rho$ than $\gamma$ is constant.
If we set $\gamma(\rho) = \log(r_0^2)$, then $R_{\phi\phi}=0$ implies
$$ e^{\beta(\rho)} = 0,$$
i.e. the metric is degenerate, which is not allowed. Consequently, we conclude that  $\gamma'(\rho)\neq 0$ and that $\gamma$ is a monotonic function of $\rho$. We can now safely make the coordinate transformation $r^2 = e^{\gamma(\rho)}$, and return to the usual derivation of the Schwarzschild metric.

Thanks for the answer! Where are the $R_{tt} = 0, R_{\rho \rho}=0$ coming from? my guess is that you are using staticitity to obtain them, but make it more explicit.

They are the components of the Ricci tensor. The vacuum Einstein Equation is simply the Ricci = 0

Also, note that use of the imperative in your comment is rather rude.

for $R_{\rho \rho} = 0$ I am getting instead $\gamma''(\rho) = \frac{\beta'(\rho)}{4}( 2 \gamma'(\rho) + \alpha'(\rho) ) -\frac{1}{4} \alpha'(\rho)^2 -\frac{1}{2} \alpha''(\rho) - \frac{1}{2} \gamma'(\rho)^2$. It is weird that I am getting both $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ 2nd derivatives on $R_{\rho \rho}$

You can eliminate the $\alpha''$ using $R_{tt}=0$

ok after incorporating 1st equation into the 2nd I get almost the same as you, I get an extra factor of 2 on the $\gamma'$ but I think it might not be important for this calculation

ok so if the function were non-monotonic, it would have to have $\gamma' = 0$ at some point, at which it would get stuck there for all neighboring values of the parameter, and it would be constant. That would be enough proof right there that the function cannot be non-monotonic in a nontrivial way, hence the reparametrization is always valid in a spherically symmetric static vacuum.  No need to appeal to $R_{\phi \phi} = 0$. Thank you !

btw by the same argument this monotonicity also applies to $\alpha$

I believe I've seen this reparametrization also used in contexts where vacuum is not assumed. Is not clear from your answer if you believe the reparametrization is only valid in vacuum or is also valid when matter is present?
